# Getting GeoJSON from Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, geojson

I would like to have an option to save the geoJSON file from Google Spreadsheets.

The issue has been raised here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140995/publishing-google-sheet-to-web-as-geojson-file

although the plugin available here:

https://github.com/mapbox/geo-googledocs/

doesn't work because the geocode receiving the error message:

https://github.com/mapbox/geo-googledocs/issues/42

**UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead.**

I tired to combine the existing code, provided by this plugin with the code proposed as a way to fixing this issue:

https://gist.github.com/hidrodixtion/c3a6b6ba7af624d1800625efb7a40fbd

```
 The code name is Geo.js as per the plugin provided above
```

I put the function `doGet` above the Geocoders as per below:

```
// Global variables
 function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
activeRange = ss.getActiveRange(),
settings = {};

var geocoders = {
yahoo: {
```

... another part of the code available here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mapbox/geo-googledocs/master/MapBox.js

unfortunately it doesn't work.

It seems like I don't know where I must [superseed the depreciated UiApp function with the HTML service](https://github.com/cobeisfresh/localizable-sheet-script/issues/5). 
The problem is, that I don't know what part of the code in the Geo plugin should be replaced. It might be really helpful as the plugin can do the geocoding either.[image]

My another part of combination was as follows:
I changed the code:
     // Create a new UI
      var app = UiApp.createApplication()
    .setTitle('Export GeoJSON')
    .setStyleAttribute('width', '460')
    .setStyleAttribute('padding', '20');

into:

```
 var app = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().setWidth(800).setHeight(600);
.setTitle('Export GeoJSON') //line 105
.setStyleAttribute('width', '460')
.setStyleAttribute('padding', '20');
```

but once I save now I get this:
Syntax error. (line 105, file "Geo")

I picked up this code from here:

https://gist.github.com/hidrodixtion/c3a6b6ba7af624d1800625efb7a40fbd
line 141

Does anybody knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: You want to convert the values in the Spreadsheet to the geoJSON data as a file. And you want to use [geo-googledocs](https://github.com/mapbox/geo-googledocs). If my understanding is correct, it is required to convert [`gjDialog()`](https://github.com/mapbox/geo-googledocs/blob/master/MapBox.js#L96) to HTML. In this case, in order to test the script, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and the sample geoJSON data you expect? Of course, please move your personal information.

Comment: Hi, I found the code, which is responsible for this UiApp function:
// Create a new UI
  var app = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().setWidth(800).setHeight(600);
    .setTitle('Export GeoJSON')
    .setStyleAttribute('width', '460')
    .setStyleAttribute('padding', '20');

in place  var app = UiApp.createApplication() I put var app = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().setWidth(800).setHeight(600);
but as a result I got Syntax error. (line 105, file "Geo")
where line 105 is:
.setTitle('Export GeoJSON')

Should I remove all stuff below then?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you add the script in your question as the additional information? By this, it will be the high readability.

Comment: I already did this, thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. Can you provide your HTML code?

Comment: There is no HTML code, because I attached the .js code into the Google Spreadsheets -> tools->script editor->new code...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful.

Comment: No worries, COuld you help me to solve this out  mate?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot propose the sample script because I have no sample data and I cannot test it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: This is why I posted this query :( Not enough skills for getting around with it